# How to get the value between different models

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 models that I would like to be able to get the string of each of them and throw it inside my const to be able to generate a PDF file. These models contain the id of the customer's contract, as well as the id of the project. How can I import the model inside my react project, so that I can extract this information? I would like to do something like:

```
Contract: `'${contract.contracNumber}'`
```

but I can't get the contract number value because I'm in a different folder

Comment: Hello LaraF. Is this data just in PDFs or already in code as a variable but just in a different folder?

Comment: It is already in a code as variable but just in a different folder

Comment: Ok. So the thing needs to be exported from the other folder. Either inline ... or as a class. export const contract. Then in your react  file import {contract} from '../path/to/your/other/file'